# Magento 2: how to set role to user programmatically

Tags: magento2, user-roles, user, role

and also an role

```
$roleAuthModel = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Authorization\Model\Role');            
            $roleAuthModel->setName("cool role")
                ->setPid(0) //set parent role id of your role
                ->setRoleType("G")
                ->setUserType(UserContextInterface::USER_TYPE_ADMIN);
            $roleAuthModel->save();

        $userModel->setUserName("bbbb");
        $userModel->setFirstName("cccc");
        $userModel->setLastName("dddd");
        $userModel->setEmail("aaaa@bbbb.com");
        $userModel->setPassword('Adfasdas322323das');
        $userModel->save();
```

How can I relate and set "**cool role**" to my new user "**bbbb**" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set role to admin user using `role` and `user` models.

```
/** @var \Magento\Authorization\Model\Role $role */
$role = $this->getRole();
/** @var $model \Magento\User\Model\User */
$user = $this->getUser();
$user->setRoleId($role->getId());

$user->save();
```

*In your case:*

```
$userModel->setRoleId($roleAuthModel->getId());
$userModel->save();
```

*Source:* `\Magento\User\Controller\Adminhtml\User\Save::execute`